# Python/LXML - Children node returning 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

Here is a sample of the XML tree I am traversing:

```
<entry dataset="Swiss-Prot" created="1993-07-01+01:00" modified="2013-04-03+01:00" version="144">
  <accession>P31750</accession>
  <accession>Q62274</accession>
  <accession>Q6GSA6</accession>
  <name>AKT1_MOUSE</name>
  <protein>
    <recommendedName>
      <fullName>RAC-alpha serine/threonine-protein kinase</fullName>
      <ecNumber>2.7.11.1</ecNumber>
    </recommendedName>
    <alternativeName>
      <fullName>AKT1 kinase</fullName>
    </alternativeName><alternativeName>
      <fullName>Protein kinase B</fullName>
    <alternativeName>
      <fullName>Some other value</fullName>
    </alternativeName><alternativeName>
     ..........
```

I am trying to get to `alternativeName`. I do not have any trouble getting to `recommended name`, so I try the same approach with `alternativeName`. However, the `Python` interpretor outputs the following error message:

```
   for child in protein.find("{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}alternativeName"):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Here is the `Python` code I am using to get at these elements. Again, the code works fine for `recommendedName` but NOT for `alternativeName`. Thanks for any help!

```
alt_shortnames = []
alt_fullnames = []

protein = e.find("{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}protein")
for child in protein.find("{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}alternativeName"):
    if child.tag == "{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}fullName":
        alt_fullnames.append(child.text)
    if child.tag == "{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}shortName":
        alt_shortnames.append(child.text)

temp_dict["alternativeFullNames"] = alt_fullnames
temp_dict["alternativeShortNames"] = alt_shortnames
```

Comment: You need to verify *why* `alternativeName` is not being found. Iterate in an interactive session over the `protein` children and see what tags are there. Are you certain that the `alternativeName` tag is *always* present? Could it be that it is sometimes not there? If so, test for `None` and move on if it is't available.

Comment: What happened to your other answer? I believe that was correct, I need to use `findall` instead of `find`. It seem to be working now. Add the answer back and I will accept it.

Comment: Also, thanks for the extra help!

Comment: Right, returned the answer, but I fear that it might be wrong still. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `protein.find()`; the [`.find()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) returns either the found element or `None` if nothing is found.

If you expect to find a *sequence* of elements, use [`.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall). That method always returns an iterable (possibly empty):

```
for altName in protein.findall("{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}alternativeName"):
    for child in altName:
        if child.tag == "{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}fullName":
            alt_fullnames.append(child.text)
        if child.tag == "{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}shortName":
            alt_shortnames.append(child.text)
```

Comment: I think the OP deliberately tries to iterate over the found element to get its children. Maybe I'm too sleepy though

Comment: @LevLevitsky: ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: Your solution did allow the parsing to finish. I still have empty values for those lists, so something else must be wrong. But using `findall` at least allowed the parser to pass over the entire document.

Comment: @Houdini I mean that `findall('...alternativeName')` will return `alternativeName` elements, but you want to access their children.

Comment: So you think maybe I should go one level further in the tree? because that may explain why my lists are returned empty. Hmm, on second thought, isnt that what `for child in protein.findall(...alternativeName)` is doing? Iterating through the children of `alternativeName` elements?

Comment: @Houdini: your sample has multiple `alternativeName` tags; I suspect that your document, *in places*, has 0 alternative names, and more than 0 in others. `.findall()` is then the correct method to use, but it'll return a list of `alternativeName` tags found.